# How do import exclude all tablespaces?

Tags: database, oracle11g, impdp

I would like to do an import with the IMPDP that it not try to import the tablespaces.

I know I can use this expression:

```
exclude = tablespace: "IN ('TABLESPACE001', 'TABLESPACE002', 'TABLESPACE00N')
```

in the parfile, but I wouldn't like have list all tablespaces.

Is there a command or configuration for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put

```
EXCLUDE=TABLESPACE
```

in parfile without specifying other settings.

My parfile file looks like this:

```
userid="/ as sysdba"
directory=DATAPUMP 
full=Y 
EXCLUDE=TABLESPACE
EXCLUDE=SCHEMA:"IN ('QS_CB','PERFSTAT','QS_ADM','PM','SH','HR','OE','ODM_MTR','WKPROXY','ANONYMOUS','OWNER','SYS','SYSTEM','SCOTT','SYSMAN','XDB','DBSNMP','EXFSYS','OLAPSYS','MDSYS','WMSYS','WKSYS','DMSYS','ODM','EXFSYS','CTXSYS','ORDPLUGINS','SQLTXPLAIN','OUTLN','TSMSYS','XS$NULL','TOAD','STREAM','SPATIAL_CSW_ADMIN','SPATIAL_WFS_ADMIN','SI_INFORMTN_SCHEMA','QS','QS_CBADM','QS_CS','QS_ES','QS_OS','QS_WS','PA_AWR_USER','OWBSYS_AUDIT','OWBSYS','ORDSYS','ORDDATA','ORACLE_OCM','MGMT_VIEW','MDDATA','FLOWS_FILES','FLASHBACK','AWRUSER','APPQOSSYS','APEX_PUBLIC_USER','APEX_030200','FLOWS_020100')"
dumpfile=DATABASE01.EXPDP
logfile=DATABASE01.log
```

Now when I run the import

```
impdp parfile=parfile.par
```

The import does not try to create tablespaces.